# change dotnetnuke file manager default address

Tags: dotnetnuke

I need to change DotNetNuke file manager default address, to save files in another system.

Can you help me?

Comment: What version of DotNetNuke? Do you know if you are using the RadMenu or FckEditor versions of the File Manager?

Comment: Also, can you please clarify what you mean by another system? Do you mean another directory on the same machine, or do you mean another web server?

Answer (score 0):

If you can wait a little, DotNetNuke 6.0 is about to be released. It includes the new Folder Provider API, which will let you create your own provider to work with files stored wherever you need. In fact, Professional and Enterprise Editions will include Azure and AmazonS3 Folder Providers.